# How do I make this responsive layout with CSS?

Tags: css

Sorry, I'm a total noob with css and web stuff.

I want to create a responsive grid layout to preserve these ratios:

- B.width/C.width = 5/7
- A.width = B.width
- C.height = 100% screen height
- A.width = B.width

Here's an illustration where A, B, and C should all be `div` elements.

```
|--5--|---7---|
|     |       |
|  B  5   C   |
|     |       |
|-----|       |
|  A  1       |
|-----|-------|
```

What I've tried doesn't work for several reasons:

- When the window is small, the columns stack up on each other in rows
- The "A" div is well below the "B" div because of how far the "C" div extends
- The height of C is not 100% the height of the window.

Here's the code for it

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span5">
        <div class="well">
            B
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span7">
        <div class="well">
            C
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span5">
        <div class="well">
            A
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use percentages if you want the boxes to behave the same regardless of screen size. Mind though, that for small screens it might be better to display the blocks underneath each other and that is also the power of a grid system as introduced by Bootstrap.

Anyway for a simple and pure CSS fixed percentages solution:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%; /* This is to make the height percentages work */
}

.A, .B, .C { /* This is just to show the boxes */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid silver;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-right-color: black;
}

.C {
  width: 58.33%; /* 7/12, rounded down */
  height: 100%; /* Relative to parent. Have a look at `vh` instead of % for viewport height */
  float: right; /* Float to the right, so A and B will move left of C*/
}
.B,
.A {
  width: 41.66%; /* 5/12, rounded down  */
}
.B {
  height: 83.33%; /* 5/6, Relative to parent (= body) */
}
.A {
  height: 16.66%; /* 1/6 */
}
```

```html
<div class="C">C</div>
<div class="B">B</div>
<div class="A">A</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of Bootstrap. I do believe you have your reasons. But it's always best to use the latest.

This is possible. Think of the two columns as two columns, and the left two portions inside one single column.

Therefore:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <!-- this is where you keep the left two divs, forget about their width, they will occupy the whole space -->
        <div id="left-1"></div>
        <div id="left-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```